Evaluate $ x^2 = \sin(2x), x≠0 $

There should be another solution ($x \approx0.967$), but can it be done without doing graphs?
I tried drawing a triangle to solve but it failed miserably.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

@Assorted69: Try numerical methods - like Newton's Method.

This equation has no nice algebraic solution. You will have to use numerical methods - essentially what you call "graphs".

Another way to solve it is to iterate $f(x)=\sqrt{\sin(2x)}$, which will converge to that attracting fixed point.

$x^2=\sin 2x$. Taylor series of $\sin 2x$ approximated to third order:
$\sin 2x = 2x-8x^3/6+(35x^5/120)$.
$-4x^3/3-x^2+2x=0\implies x=0 $ or $x= \frac{1 - \sqrt{1+32/3}}{-8/3}$.
$-4x^2/3-x+2=0$.
That will only get you in the ball park. Using the 5th order Taylor approximation (extra term in parentheses above would give you a more accurate answer.
Moo's suggestion can get you further.
Let $x_0= \frac{1 - \sqrt{1+32/3}}{-8/3}$
and $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2-\sin 2x_n}{2x_n-2\cos 2x_n}$
Repeat.
